# Background worker to async await task

Tags: c#, async-await, devexpress, backgroundworker

Below is the sample code, this uses devexpress bareditItem(progressbar) to show progress when data is loaded. I would like to know if there is a way I could show the same progress bar(show progress when data is loading) using async await and task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProgressBar {
    public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm {

        DataTable workTable;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            workTable = new DataTable("Records");
            workTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            workTable.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(String));
        }

        //this data varies from 0 to 50,000 rows
        private void LoadData(DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                workTable.Rows.Add(i, String.Format("Record {0}", i));
                this.backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, i);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            LoadData(e);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
            DataTable up = workTable.Clone();
            this.barEditItem1.EditValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
            gridControl1.DataSource = workTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be converted and simplified using the `async/await` pattern and the [Progress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class to ensure that the progress report update occurs on the correct thread:

```
namespace ProgressBar {
    public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm {

        DataTable workTable;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            workTable = new DataTable("Records");
            workTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            workTable.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(String));
        }

        //this data varies from 0 to 50,000 rows
        private void LoadData(IProgress<int> progress) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                workTable.Rows.Add(i, String.Format("Record {0}", i));
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // 1. This replaces: backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged
            var progress = new Progress<int>(
              i => 
              {
                // This code will execute on the UI thread, as it should
                DataTable up = workTable.Clone();
                this.barEditItem1.EditValue = i;
              });

            // 2. This replaces: backgroundWorker1_DoWork
            await Task.Run(() => this.LoadData(progress));

            // 3. This replaces: backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted
            gridControl1.DataSource = workTable;
        }
    }
}
```

I left in a few lines of code that you have, that I don't think you actually need, like the `Thread.Sleep` and `DataTable up = workTable.Clone();`, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Ooooooh, I didn't know about `IProgress<T>`. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker` is an obsolete feature for me (Since the release of the async-await feature). Try not to use it from now on. This is the equivalent using the fancy async-await:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await LoadData();
}

private async Task LoadData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        workTable.Rows.Add(i, String.Format("Record {0}", i));

        DataTable up = workTable.Clone(); // useless but copied from your code
        this.barEditItem1.EditValue = i;
    }
    gridControl1.DataSource = workTable;
}
```

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is not obsolete.

Comment: @LarsTech It is not recommended to be used after the release of async-await.

Answer (score -1):

Sure there is. Don't use a background worker at all as it's obsolete.

Here's some (untested) code that should get you on your way. The `SynchronizationContext` prevents Cross-threaded exceptions. There might be a better way to do that, but that's what I use.

```
namespace ProgressBar
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Threading;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {

        private DataTable workTable;
        private SynchronizationContext _context;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            workTable = new DataTable("Records");
            workTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            workTable.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(String));
        }

        private async Task LoadData()
        {
            const int iterations = 1001; //whatever you want...

            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                workTable.Rows.Add(i, String.Format("Record {0}", i));
                this._context.Post(() =>
                {
                    this.UpdateWorkProgress((int) i /iterations)
                });
            }
        }

        private void UpdateWorkProgress(int percent)
        {
            this.barEditItem1.EditValue = percent;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await this.LoadData();
            gridControl1.DataSource = workTable;
        }        
    }
}
```